# Block not completing in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl

I'm relatively new to iOS development but I'm working on an application to get a better understanding of development. I'm working with a web service and want to check the credentials a user enters. To do this I am making a simple get request with their credentials and then checking the http status for 200. Here is my code below:

```
-(BOOL)checkCredentials:(NSString *)username withPassword:(NSString *)password{

    NSString *requestString = @"SOME URL";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSData *userPasswordData = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", username, password] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *base64EncodedCredential = [userPasswordData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    NSString *authString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", base64EncodedCredential];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig=[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    sessionConfig.HTTPAdditionalHeaders=@{@"Authorization":authString};

    self.session=[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig];
    __block BOOL success = NO;

    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        if(!error){
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
            if (httpResp.statusCode == 200) {
                success = YES;
            }
        }
        NSMutableDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"%@", jsonObject);
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
    }];

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

    [dataTask resume];
    return success;
}
```

I was going to use a semaphore to wait for the block to complete so I can check the status code and then return. But first it seems like my code just hangs, and I think that because I don't have a release, but that's not allowed with ARC. I'm not sure why it's hanging. Is there a better way to wait for the block to complete (without a semaphore) so I can return whether my credentials are valid?

Also is there a better way to pass the username and password so that it's not possible for someone to spoof the username and password?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would rather not wait for the block to complete and block the thread, instead block the UI(activity indicator, partially transparent black screen).

Comment: @user Please rewrite your code as suggested by Jason so that it behaves asynchronously. Right now you are making it synchronous which gives a really bad UX and more over its not a good approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think simple!

Make your own `completionHandler` so that you won't deal with the `return` anymore, the caller will take the responsibility of result verification instead.

There's one thing you need to keep in mind, that if you want to modify anything related to UI (User Interface), you need to dispatch your completion block to main queue or you will get unexpected behavior, see more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155309/ui-get-blocked-when-using-nsurlsession).

Change your `return` type to `void` and add a `completion block`:

```
-(void)checkCredentials:(NSString *)username withPassword:(NSString *)password completionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error))myCompletion
{

    NSString *requestString = @"http://google.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        // Here you return exactly what the NSURLSessionDataTask downloaded
        // and pass it to the caller as an another completion block
        myCompletion(data, response, error);
    }];


    [dataTask resume];
}
```

Caller's code, I assume that `self` is the caller:

```
[self checkCredentials:@"" withPassword:@"" completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if(!error){
            // Result verification's here 
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
            if (httpResp.statusCode == 200) {
                NSLog(@"SUCESS");
            }
        }
    }];
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the explanation and code example.

Answer (score 3):

You code stops waiting for a semaphore and `[dataTask resume]` is never executed.

```
dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER); <=== waits here

[dataTask resume];                                    <=== never reached
```

I'd suggest not using the semaphore here. Do the work in your block instead.

As to username/password. If you worry about spoofing then SSL layer on top of HTTP is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a really dangerous pattern, because this call is going to block until the network request completes. If this is on the main thread, your app will stop responding and the watchdog may kill you.

That warning aside, the reason the block doesn't complete is because the network task is never started. You trap on your semaphore *before* you call `resume`, so your task never runs. I would also, personally use a `dispatch_group` to do the waiting.

To make it better, you would need to rewrite it asynchronously. Basically have your app continue to function, maybe disable the inputs, until the call completes, then run a block to re-enable them, or show an error:

```
// Assume your login button and whatever are exposed as properties here
self.loginButton.enabled = NO;
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
  if(!error){
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
    if (httpResp.statusCode == 200) {
      success = YES;
    }
  }
  NSMutableDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
  NSLog(@"%@", jsonObject);
  // Need to be back on the main queue, the call is complete
  self.loginButton.enabled = YES;
}];
[dataTask resume];
```

Or, just to keep it the way you have it, but resolve the immediate issue, re-order your trap so that it happens after the task resumes:

```
[dataTask resume];
dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER); // might want to time out here instead of waiting forever
return success;
```

Comment: Oh wow. I didn't realize what I was doing would be such a bad idea.Thanks for letting me know. I want to get this right and not just hack together a solution. The original reason I wanted to use a semaphore was that my `checkCredentials` was returning before I was able to check the status code. I now see why this is bad, but won't your solution also return before `success` could be set to `YES`? If this is true how do I prevent that? Or I'm I still misunderstanding something? Thank you for your help.