# Why does my UI update when I explicitiy leave out return to main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

Doing UI updates have to be done on the main thread according to this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/23155684/1898829

```
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response,
                                NSError *error) {
                if (data != nil) {
                    NSDictionary *responseDictionary =
                    [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                    options:kNilOptions
                                                      error:&error];
//                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                            CarListModel *carListModel = [[CarListModel alloc]
                                                          initWithArray:responseDictionary[@"placemarks"]];
                            completion(carListModel, error);
//                        });
                    } else {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                            completion(nil, error);
                        });
                    }
                }] resume];
```

When commenting out the dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ my app still works the same as before. My tableview gets updated and my activity indicator stops.

This completion block goes to a view model which has a completion block which goes to the view controller. Nowhere am I saying it must go back on the main thread.

Why does my UI not get blocked or is it possible for it to return to the main thread without me explicitly setting it with the

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
```

Comment: You are not "returning" to the main thread. The main threads runs in parallel. `-dataTaskWithRequest` likely uses a queue that runs on anthoer thread. Therefore you cannot block the main thread. Only code on the main thread can block the main thread.

Comment: Is my UI changes not being done on the main thread then and if they are being done on the main thread, why?

Comment: If you run the completion handler outside a dispatch to the main queue, it is executed outside the main thread. Since I do not know the code of the completion handler, I cannot say, what is done there on what queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that UI updates have to be done on the main thread. You are mistaken to believe that not doing it on the main thread will lead to no action happening.  If only that were the case.  If you do UI updates not on the main thread the app can fail in strange and unexpected ways AT ANY TIMES.  This means that it can crash a few minutes later.  Animations could suddenly stop working. Views can randomly disappear or appear.  Navigations bars could be out of places.  In other words the behavior is undefined.

Therefore you should

1) always use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{` when updating UI from a background thread

2) if you have a methods that might accidentally be called from a background thread, protect them with something like:

```
if (![NSThread mainThread]) {
    // log to crash reporter without crashing
    NSError* error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"accessing UI outside of main thread" code:-1 userInfo:nil];
    [[Crashlytics sharedInstance] recordError:error withAdditionalUserInfo:@{@"file":__FILE__, @"line":@(__LINE__)}];
    return;
}
```